# flutter emulator error [ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -1073740791 after startup

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, emulation

I am getting this error everytime. Please help . The emulator used to work perfectly. Due to some reasons I had reinstalled my OS . EVERY SINCE THAT I AM GETTING THIS ERROR.

Starting device daemon...

```
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -1073740791 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
[ERR] INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 28d2:df1:6401:0:f0b7:df1:6401:0 (2x)
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\91893\.android\flutter_emulator_2.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
[ERR] WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
[ERR] I0102 16:24:23.688707   12216 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
[ERR] added library vulkan-1.dll
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.
```

I was expecting the emulator to run after several failed attempts I am posting this error in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio
you can run `Help: Start extension bisect` from the command palette (F1)
then stop It and reopen vs code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).